# How to use Popen with openssl in Python 3.x

Tags: python, bash

I am porting code from Python 2 to Python 3 and I realized that the m2crypto module is not ported, yet. Unfortunately I want to do S/MIME signing and now I thought I could use subproccess.Popen instead. I want to give an unsigned plist to openssl and get it S/MIME signed. I do this in automx (see https://github.com/sys4/automx)

What I want is:

Bash-example:

```
echo "Test " | openssl smime -sign -signer server.crt -inkey server.key -nodetach -outform der
```

I tried this in Python:

```
import subprocess as s

cmd = "/usr/bin/openssl smime -sign -signer " + sign_cert +\
      "-inkey " + sign_key + "-nodetach -outform der"
process = s.Popen(
    cmd.split(),
    stdin=s.PIPE,
    stdout=s.PIPE,
    stderr=s.PIPE,
    shell=True)

plist_signed, errors = process.communicate(
    input=plist_unsigned)

if errors is not None:
    logging.error("Call to openssl failed: %s", str(errors))
    return plist_unsigned
```

Unfortunately this doe not work. openssl seems to interpred the stdin stuff as a command.

Comment: what are you trying to input?

Comment: automx creates a plist and that shall be signed. The plist is created with the plistlib in python using a dict().

Comment: That sounds good. I will try this out :-)

Comment: I still have issues. What I do not understand is: I thought the "|" is a pipe. Meaning that it captures from stdout and redirects to stdin. So why do I need a process "/bin/echo", if I directly could serve text to openssl's stdin? What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Just saw you have shell set to True. When passing a list of args leave it as the default False. If you were using the pipe character and passing a single string you would set shell to True

Comment: I finally got it working. Kopefully :-) It seems the openssl call succeeds even openssl prints out an error tht it could not write the rand file. Currently I ignore this, as it seems to work.